# JOIN on partition_id or hobt_id?

Tags: sql-server, dmv

I'm joining the SQL Server DMVs `sys.column_store_segments` and `sys.partitions`. Logically, I would join on `partition_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.column_store_segments AS s
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
 ON p.partition_id = s.partition_id
```

But I have also seen examples that join on `hobt_id`, for instance [in the canonical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-column-store-segments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#examples):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.column_store_segments AS s
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
 ON p.hobt_id = s.hobt_id
```

Does it matter in practice? I guess it is guaranteed to be the same unique heap-or-b-tree anyway?

Interestingly enough Microsoft [writes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-column-store-segments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> You can uniquely identify a segment using <`hobt_id`,
> `partition_id`, `column_id`>, <`segment_id`>.

But IIRC, from `hobt_id` and `partition_id` only *one* would be necessary here...?

Comment: Yes only one is necessary. For joining sys.column_store_segments and sys.partitions, you can choose either partition_id or hobt_id depending on what you’re interested in. If you’re interested in partitions join on partition_id. If interested in the heap or B-tree, join on hobt_id.  As to multiple alternative unique identifiers; they aren't interchangeable, but also they aren't redundant, they are there for different purposes.

Comment: I meant one is redundant *to uniquely identify a segment*. I understand why it's useful to have both in the DMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Not only are they as unique, they are [the exact same thing](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/partition_id-vs-hobt_id#post-1592755)!

> They're the same thing. They were added as separate columns to support
> a feature that was planned, partially added to SQL 2005 and later
> scrapped.

So in fact they *are* interchangeable.